# Find comma separated value in a column by using comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, find-in-set

I have a a column `item_id_list` with comma separated id such as this:

[image]

I can search them by using `FIND_IN_SET()` such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM task_detail WHERE FIND_IN_SET('21', item_id_list)
```

but I need to check whether multiple id did exist in the row but adding another id to search will not work as stated in the docs.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

> This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a
>   comma (,) character.

```
SELECT * FROM task_detail WHERE FIND_IN_SET('21, 79', item_id_list)
```

Without changing my table structure, how do I solve this problem? Right now looping `FIND_IN_SET()` by number of id is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a OR with find_in_set

```
    SELECT * FROM task_detail 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('21', item_id_list)
    OR  FIND_IN_SET('79', item_id_list)
```